# Can't resize d3 v6 in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to resize my svg with width and height from state:

```
  const [svgWidth, setSvgWidth] = useState(350);

  const [svgHeight, setSvgHeight] = useState(250);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select("#epi-chart")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight);

    const margin = { top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 },
      width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);

    const y = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, height]).padding(0.4);

    const g = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain([0, d3.max(mockData, (d) => Number(d.col1)) as number]);

    y.domain(
      mockData.map(function (d) {
        return d.letter;
      })
    );

    g.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(mockData)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("fill", "rgba(105, 129, 148, 0.4)")
      .attr("class", "bar1")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", (d) => y(d.letter) as number)
      .attr("width", (d) => x(Number(d.col1)))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("rx", 21)
      .attr("ry", 21);

    g.selectAll(".bar2")
      .data(mockData)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("fill", "url(#bg-gradient)")
      .attr("filter", "drop-shadow(0 0 4px #418bfa)")
      .attr("class", "bar2")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", (d) => y(d.letter) as number)
      .attr("width", (d) => x(Number(d.col2)))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("rx", 21)
      .attr("ry", 21);
  }, [svgWidth, svgHeight]);
```

i am using material ui and i change width and height like this:

```
 const isScreenDownMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isScreenDownMd) {
      setSvgWidth(300);
      setSvgHeight(200);
    }
  }, [isScreenDownMd]);
```

but the result i get is like this which is messed up:

[image]

why is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put **width** and **height** in one object:

```
  const [svgSize, setSvgSize] = useState({width: 350, height: 250});
```

, then on change of `isScreenDownMd`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isScreenDownMd) {
      setSvgSize({width: 300, height: 200});
    }
  }, [isScreenDownMd]);
```

... and:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select("#epi-chart")
      .attr("width", svgSize.width)
      .attr("height", svgSize.height);
    ...
  }, [svgSize]);
```